# Sockets won't connect after Windows 8.1 update

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am currently working on a project that involves the use of sockets. The program was working just fine, but after a windows 8.1 update on my computer, either the client socket is sending out a signal to be accepted or the server socket isn't receiving the signal so it can accept. I tried to use it on my emulator and it worked just fine. In addition, I have updated my GPU drivers to see if this could be fixed, but they still won't connect. The program doesn't crash and give me an error; it just sits there and waits. Does anyone have any ideas? Perhaps the update is blocking my peer to peer connection? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: EVen if it worked before, show some code. To clarify. connect() is hanging? How long did you wait? What are you passing to connect?

Comment: Either the creation of the socket or the server socket at .accept() is hanging. I have it wait 5 seconds (I've also tried longer and this doesn't work),but it never needed more than half a second before. On the creation of the server socket I am passing the IPv4 and port number.

Comment: Maybe the windows upgrade resulted in different firewall settings?

Comment: I thought the same thing and tried making a port exception and shutting it off completely. This, however, did not work.

Comment: I fixed it. For some reason I had to reset my settings to default and then unblock it again. That's one weird glitch